# How to perform auto-increment with dependency on column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to figure out how to do an Auto-increment based on change in values in a different column as shown below

This is what I am getting right now

```
OtherID | AUTOINCREMENT
--------+---------------
A       | 1
A       | 2 
B       | 3
C       | 4
D       | 5
D       | 6
```

This is what I am hoping for

```
OtherID | AUTOINCREMENT
--------+---------------
A       | 1
A       | 1 
B       | 2
C       | 3
D       | 4
D       | 4
```

Comment: what do you expect to get for A,A,B,A ? 1,1,2,1 or 1,1,2,3?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a windows function in SQL Server

```
select
   OtherID,
   row_number() over (partition by OtherID order by OtherID) as AutoIncrement
from
   SomeTable
```

The `order by OtherID` works here assuming your `OtherID` is what you state it is... a character starting with A and moving up the alphabet. Otherwise, you can replace it with `(select null)`

```
select
   OtherID,
   row_number() over (partition by OtherID order by (select null)) as AutoIncrement
from
   SomeTable
```

**EDIT**

```
select
   OtherID,
   dense_rank() over (order by cast(left(OtherID,len(OtherID) - 1) as int)) as AutoIncrement
from
   SomeTable
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your code with the (select null) since 'otherId' column is not alphabet, it is still not working properly. Here are the exact values for otherId column. It starts with 1H,2H,2H,3H....100H,101H. So in this case I would like the incremental value to be 1,2,2,3...etc

Comment: The value would still be incremented based on the partition but the order of this increment is hard because you are mixing numeric and character data

Comment: @Rbird see the edit based off your new information. This is why accurate test data is so important...

Answer (score 0):

try this 
using `row_number()`

```
select Row_number() over(partition by OtherID  order by
 (select 1)),AUTOINCREMENT from mytable
```